# you might be able to put the ashes

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider this sentence of mine, please:

> If you wanted to enhance the soil, you ***might be able*** to put the ashes in your garden.

Does the second part of the above sentence suggest that the speaker is ***doubting*** "*your*" ability to put the ashes **OR** does it suggest that the speaker is ***not sure*** about their suggestion that "putting the ashes enhances the soil?"

Comment: It could be neither and something else. We need more context to say for definite. Is it from a novel, a film script? Supposing for example that the suggestion is said to someone who is in a fragile state emotionally, it could be just a gentle unassuming suggestion as to what to do with the ashes of a dear one. The remains of an evening smoking places a whole different set of possibilities at our feet. Context is all.

Comment: It was mine. I was just wondering how "might be able to" could be used to give suggestions.

Comment: *If you want to enhance the soil, put ashes in your garden.* There's no need for the qualifier.